# Google Drive Audio Repo URL for JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, url, audio, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to make a radio station {music player} with a public google drive audio repo but URLs of audios changing constantly and URL convertors not working because it's last for few minute. has anyone such a issue or how possibly can solve the thing. any suggestion {approach wise}?
I tried a simple JS audio player but since audio URLs constantly changing from google drive side, it's not working properly.

Comment: At the risk of going off-topic, I'm not sure that using Google Drive would be the most stable of solutions. The reason - you might run into "Download Quota Exceeded for This File" errors, and there's no real way of knowing what that quota is. That would make your more popular audio files frequently unavailable. To say nothing of the potential copyright issues.

Comment: these audio materials is not copyrighted . it's collection of speeches .downloading the thing is not the case because it's too much. and I'm looking for some web scrapping techniques. a tool to go and generate the right link each time a viewer push the play button. and I think it\s possible some how.